# Excel VBA to SQL Server - Transition Matrix

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have code in VBA that works to generate a transition matrix on data in excel. I now have access to a huge SQL DB with ~2MM rows of information and would like to generate a transition matrix which looks something like this:

[image: Tarnsition Matrix]

In any case here is the VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Function COHORT(id, dat, rat, _
Optional classes As Integer, Optional ystart, Optional yend)
'Function is written for data sorted according to issuers and rating dates (ascending),
'rating classes numbered from 1 to classes, last rating class=default, not rated has number "0"

If IsMissing(ystart) Then ystart = Year(Application.WorksheetFunction.min(dat))
If IsMissing(yend) Then yend = Year(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(dat)) - 1
If classes = 0 Then classes = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rat)

Dim obs As Long, k As Long, kn As Long, i As Integer, j As Integer, t As Integer
Dim ni() As Long, nij() As Long, pij() As Double, newrat As Integer
ReDim nij(1 To classes - 1, 0 To classes), ni(0 To classes)
obs = id.Rows.count

For k = 1 To obs
'Earliest cohort to which observation can belong is from year:
    t = Application.Max(ystart, Year(dat(k)))

    'Loop through cohorts to which observation k can belong
    Do While t < yend
        'Is there another rating from the same year?
        If id(k + 1) = id(k, 1) And Year(dat(k + 1)) <= t And k <> obs Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        'Is the issuer in default or not rated?
        If rat(k) = classes Or rat(k) = 0 Then Exit Do

        'Add to number of issuers in cohort
        ni(rat(k)) = ni(rat(k)) + 1

        'Determine rating from end of next year (=y+1)
        'rating stayed constant
        If id(k + 1) <> id(k) Or Year(dat(k + 1)) > t + 1 Or k = obs Then
            newrat = rat(k)
        'rating changed
        Else
            kn = k + 1
            Do While Year(dat(kn + 1)) = Year(dat(kn)) And id(kn + 1) = id(kn)
                If rat(kn) = classes Then Exit Do   'Default is absorbing!
                kn = kn + 1
            Loop
            newrat = rat(kn)
        End If

        'Add to number of transitions
        nij(rat(k), newrat) = nij(rat(k), newrat) + 1
        'Exit if observation k cannot belong to cohort of y+1
        If newrat <> rat(k) Then Exit Do
        t = t + 1
    Loop
Next k

ReDim pij(1 To classes - 1, 1 To classes + 1)

'Compute transition frequencies pij=Nij/Ni
For i = 1 To classes - 1
    For j = 1 To classes
        If ni(i) > 0 Then pij(i, j) = nij(i, j) / ni(i)
    Next j
Next i

'NR category to the end
For i = 1 To classes - 1
    If ni(i) > 0 Then pij(i, classes + 1) = nij(i, 0) / ni(i)
Next i

COHORT = pij
```

I am very new to SQL Server, can anyone help convert this for SQL? I made an attempt based on searching on internet but it didn't come close:

```
create table trans as
select a.group as from, b.group as to, count(*) as nTrans
from haveRanks as a inner join haveRanks as b
    on a.ID=b.ID and a.Date+1 = b.Date
group by a.group, b.group;
create table probs as 
select from, to, nTrans/sum(nTrans) as prob
from trans
group by from;

End Function
```

My data looks something like this:

```
ID    Date       Value
1     1/10/14    5
1     5/10/14    5
1     6/23/16    7
2     3/10/00   12
2     6/10/01    4
```

Edit: Answering Question from Comments:
1) Correct, if a Highest Rating is not supplied, the program will take the maximum number as the "default" class
2) If there is no rating for the year it is has not changed.
3) Not sure I understand this question, the Do While t < yend loops through the observations and checks if the next observations are in the same cohort, or if it's default/Not Rated it will kick out and go to the next one.

Comment: Your data does not appear to correlate to your image output...perhaps you could explain how your provided data would be transformed and show a correlated version of the output above. Also, which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: The output would be an N*N matrix . In order to run the calculation, the letters shown in the image are converted to a number as shown in "Value". So for example "AAA" = 1, "AA" =2 and so forth. I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: How is N determined? Is it always 8? Why does Value in the sample data go up to 12 but you only have 8 column headings (AAA to D) do you have a list that converts values to text?

Comment: Sorry, the image posted is just an example and not indicative of the current data. In my dataset, Value can range from 1 to 20 but the VBA code has the ability to accept any range of Value.

Comment: I had a look at the new image. So N is dynamic and is just the max Value from the data. ID in the data would correlate to issuer in the code and Value in the data correlates to rating in the code?

Comment: yep, exactly right! In the VBA function inputs - ID=id, Date = dat, and Value = rat

Comment: OK. If no one else has answered I will have a look at converting it tonight.

Comment: @SMM Any chance you can help with the code? My further attempts were not successful, I would owe you big time :)

Comment: I had a look at it on the weekend but ended up with too many questions and then got pulled away. This could be done procedurally I think (using cursors) but I was trying to accomplish it declaratively. The code talks about default and appears to be the highest rating in the data. in the case of your sample data would 12 be where defaulting happened? It looks like if there is a year with no rating you want to assume it stayed the same in that year. I didn't understand the purpose of the `Do While t < yend` loop precisely. Could you edit the question to clarify these things?

Comment: Also, I see your VBA function takes parameters. Are those parameters required for the solution or are you happy to use the defaults the function uses when they are missing?